# can't delete array that is class field

Tags: c++

I have class `cAuthorisation` that manages array of `strAuthorisation`
function `resize` prepares aray for next record.

During  `resize` , on line `delete [] data;` I have crash.

```
struct strAuthorisation 
{ 
double Amount; 
}Authorisation;

class cAuthorisation { 
public: 
    int size; 
    strAuthorisation *data; 
cAuthorisation ()
{
    size=0;
}

~cAuthorisation()
{

};

void Add(strAuthorisation )
{
    resize();
    data[size]=*value;
}

void resize() 
{
    strAuthorisation *a = new strAuthorisation[5];
    size_t newSize = size + 1 ;
    strAuthorisation *newArr = new strAuthorisation[newSize];
    memcpy( newArr, data, size * sizeof(strAuthorisation) );

    size = newSize;

    delete [] data;
    data = newArr;
}
} Authorisations;
```

Why it is not possible delete class array?

Comment: You should also be doing a check if you need to resize when you `Add` instead of resizing every single time.  And you have a memory leak in `resize` where you aren't deleting `a`

Comment: I feel a strong urge to mention `std::vector`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `a` in resize?

Answer (score 7):

It crashes because `data` is an unitialised pointer. `delete[]` on a null pointer is safe (no-op) so initialise `data` in the constructor:

```
cAuthorisation() : size(0), data(0) {}
```

Note that the class as it stands is violating [the rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Unsure if this is a learning exercise, if it is not use `std::vector<strAuthorisation>`. The [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) will dynamically grow as required and automatically destructed when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 4):

You have not initialized the `data` pointer. So you are making something like this:

```
Foo *data;
delete [] data;
```

Answer (score 0):

"data" is a pointer who's value was never initialized.